# Bose Einstein Condensation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate

We all know that the Bose Einstein distribution formula is $n=g_i/(e^{α+βi}-1).$
Where alpha is the derivative of constant number of particles that is supposed to be zero. But while studding Bose Einstein Condensation we find that specially when we study the variation of temperature when $T$ is less than initial temperature alpha is zero hence degeneracy is one. When temperature is larger then alpha is not zero and degeneracy tends to greater then one! 
Technically it seems impossible to me. How can derivative of constant number be changing  with variation with temperature. Anybody please explain?

Comment: What do you mean by "the derivative of a constant number"?

Comment: The total number of particles are constant. The derivation of constant is zero. while deriving the formula it was multiplied by alpha.